# Symfony 4: Add Twig_Extension_StringLoader

Tags: symfony, twig

In my Symfony 4 project, I have a variable containing HTML that I try to display with Twig. I want to use the `template_from_string()` function but I have to add **Twig_Extension_StringLoader** to the Twig environment.

I didn't find any information to do this simple manipulation in Symfony 4.

Comment: You can also use |raw

Comment: Using the raw filter would open the XSS vulnerability.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In one of those mysteries, the string loader extension is not loaded by default.  Never understood why.  Seems harmless enough.

S4 just needs a single line in your services file:

```
# config/services.yaml
services:
    Twig\Extension\StringLoaderExtension:
```

You can then use "bin/console debug:twig | grep string" to confirm it is available.

Comment: More precisely, it must be added to the service configuration in the `services:` section.